# Having a switch statement case label without a value

Tags: c, switch-statement

I was working around with the Switch statement when I accidentally wrote the following piece of code(on gcc in C)

```
        int a = 2;
        switch(a)
        {
                default:
                        printf("Default\n");
                case 1:
                        printf("One\n");          
                case2 :
                        printf("Two\n");
        }
```

The output I got was:

Default

One

Two

I am able to understand how this output came about, however I don't understand why this does not throw up an error, I mean I clearly don't have a case label (in case2) right? Also I have observed the same result if I right "case2" as "casex" for example. 
Whereas if I don't put in any case label it gives a compile time error.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't `case2:` give you a compiler warning? Is your query about the lack of a space there, or the lack of the `break` statements expected?

Comment: `case2` is a valid label; it's just not a `case` label in terms of the scope of the `switch` statement. Without a `break`, it is simply ignored.

Comment: The warning I got (from MSVC) was *warning C4102: 'case2': unreferenced label*.

Comment: You must insert the `break` statement after the code of each `case`.

Comment: > The warning I got (from MSVC) was warning C4102: 'case2': unreferenced label.  
As Mark Benningfield mentioned, `case2 :` is a "regular" label (for goto), not the `case` keyword.  This warning indicates there's no `goto case2;` statement in your program... the upshot here is `case2 :` isn't a case for your switch, it's just a goto label inside the switch block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am able to understand how this output came about, however I don't
>   understand why this does not throw up an error, I mean I clearly don't
>   have a case label (in case2) right?

Yes, `case2 :` is not a *case* label, but it is a valid valid ordinary label.  Any statement may be preceded by such a label.  Since you're using GCC, you could consider turning on the `-Wall` option (or specifically `-Wunused-label`), in which case GCC should warn that that label is unused (because it is not the target of any `goto` statement).

> Also I have observed the same
>   result if I right "case2" as "casex" for example.

Well, sure.  `casex :` is also a valid ordinary label.

> Whereas if I don't
>   put in any case label it gives a compile time error.

I suppose you must mean that you leave the colon, but remove the whole label text (`case2` / `casex`).  That would indeed yield invalid code.  If you removed the whole line, however, then of course that would be fine.

Comment: Apologies, by no case label what I meant was just writing "case". After reading your answer, I would presume that since case is a reserved word, it throws up an error because it isn't a possible label on its own, and the compiler treats it as a switch case label and demands a number after it.

Comment: Yes, @KartikRamesh, `case` is reserved for use as a keyword, so `case :` is neither a valid ordinary label nor a valid case label.

Answer (score 2):

you missed the `break` so the execution continue after each case (but with a != 1 to have these 3 outputs)

note `case2:` is considered as a label (for a *goto*) so is not an error

Comment: I think OP knows that.

Comment: @WeatherVane ah yes I read to fast ... in fact I read only the beginning before to answer, shame on me ^^

Comment: I thought `case2` was a typo at first, but it is repeated in the question body.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes I see ... when I decided to read the question rather than not just the code ^^

Answer (score -1):

What happens here is you got to the default label, and because you had no break, you followed through to all other cases.